# Filtering based on an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

The SQL query I am using does not seem to be filtering out the right values.

```
SELECT "- Account Optimized Custom Attributes”.OPT_PICK_0 FROM "Opty-Product Lists (RTO5)" 
WHERE
Employee."Employee Name"=ValueOf(NQ_SESSION.DISPLAYNAME) AND
"- Employee Custom Attributes".TEXT_0 LIKE '%' + "- Account Optimized Custom Attributes".OPT_PICK_0 + '%'
```

Basically the column "- Employee Custom Attributes".TEXT_0 has rows that might contain words separated by a comma (For example: Cow, Dog, Bull) and the column "- Account Optimized Custom  Attributes".OPT_PICK_0 contains ONLY single values on each row (not comma separated) (For example on each row: Dog or Deer or Bull or Cow or Horse).

I would like the to filter out values such that when "- Employee Custom Attributes".TEXT_0 contains a string separated by commas (Cow, Dog, Bull) and "- Account Optimized Custom  Attributes".OPT_PICK_0 contains Horse / Dog / Bull / Elephant each on a separate row, the final result for column "- Account Optimized Custom  Attributes".OPT_PICK_0 should be the filtered out version of both i.e. Dog / Bull only (each in separate rows).

I have used the LIKE function with % as wildcard to try to isolate each word separated by commas so the filtering works, but it doesn't seem to.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ignoring the various issues the table design (name of table, names of columns, the fact that you're storing a comma-separated list in a field), `',' + col1 + ',' like '%,' + col2 + ',%'` should work (where col2 is the single value). What result does your current query return that you expect it shouldn't?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. My original code gave no result. I modified my code and tried it with yours and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are there spaces in the comma separated values? If so, you may be required to put `', ' + col1 + ',' like '%, ' + col2 + ',%'`. e.g. http://rextester.com/LOEAL45888